# Skip records containing no field separator in awk

Tags: awk

In awk, I am using `/` as the field separator. However,there are some records in the input file that do not contain this field separator. How does awk behave for such records?
Is there any way to tell awk to skip such records?

Answer (score 2):

If there's no field separator on a line, then the line consists of a single field.

If you want to skip lines with a single field, you can start your awk program with

```
NF == 1 {next}
```

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of the answer, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Comment: @A.B. Your comment was addressed to me, not to the asker. Not that it would have been useful if you'd addressed it correctly, considering that the asker hasn't been on the site for two years.